# Cannot Go Into Debugger Mode in Eclipse Android Dev

Tags: android, debugging

I am new to Android development. I placed a breakpoint next to the  `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` and tried to debug my `main.java` as an Android application. Instead of the debugging mode coming up, the `Android Device Chooser` came up. I cannot get to the debugger mode.

My hardware device is connected, USB debugging mode is enabled, and the  `android:debugger` is set to
true in Manifest. What else can I try?

Comment: before starting debug mode you have to choose where to start the app, that's why it shows the device chooser

Comment: Even then Eclipse does not go into debugger mode.